# How to keep helper function generated HTML tags for JsViews

Tags: jsrender, jsviews

In JsRender[1] I have the custom tags {{tag data /}} to generate part of my page. According to http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/03_converters-and-encoding.html it is possible to use {{:value}} to render HTML from value too.

However in JsViews[2] where I need to put expressions in the data-link attribute of tag, if my conversion function generates HTML tags (say:

```
<div data-link="{:~conv(data)}" />
```

where conv generates HTML tags

```
function conv(data) { return '<b>' + data + '</b>'; }
```

), when inserted into the DOM the output is being filtered (i.e. output as "**...**" rather than bold). How can I disable this function in JsViews and let helper function generate markup for up-to-date data?

Thanks in advance!

[1] https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender
[2] https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, data-link on an HTML element such as `div` (basically any element other than form elements like `input` or `select`) will have a default target of `innerText`, so HTML markup in the string will be rendered as markup, not inserted into the DOM as HTML elements. (Equivalent to HTML encoding by the browser.)

However you can set a different target 'attrib' and write, for example,

`<div data-link="title{:~conv(data)}" />`

to target the `title` property of the `div`, or

`<div data-link="css-background-color{:~conv(data)}" />`

to target the background color style.

For your scenario you can write

`<div data-link="html{:~conv(data)}" />`

to target `innerHTML`. That way your data or converter or helper output can be inserted into the DOM as HTML elements. (Less secure of course...).

BTW you can add converters too, as in:

`<div data-link="html{myCnvt:~conv(data)}" />`

To come full circle, if you use the html encoder as converter, as in:

`<div data-link="html{html:~conv(data)}" />`

which can also be writtne in the abbreviated form:

`<div data-link="html{>~conv(data)}" />`

then that will actually use `innerHTML` but will add HTML encoding before insertion.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation and thanks for the great libraries!